# What are ways to detect race conditions on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, valgrind

What tools have you used to detect race conditions for multithreaded programs in Linux.

I use the **helgrind** tool from **valgrind**, but I've noticed that sometimes it misses race conditions.

Comment: I suggest to change the question to "What are ways to detect race conditions on Linux?". Some people seem not to like it the way it is currently phrased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use **DRD** Valgrind tool along with **helgrind**. Though I have not tried **DRD**, it should detect some bugs missed by **helgrind** - so it worth to use both tools to detect more bugs.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try [ThreadSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer).

It [differs](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizerVsOthers) from Helgrind in that in hybrid mode it "may give more false positives, but is much faster, more predictable and finds more real races."

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** I somehow missed that you mentioned helgrind. However, in my text there are pointers to why helgrind could miss such cases.

You can use **[helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html)** from the valgrind toolkit

> Helgrind is a Valgrind tool for detecting synchronisation errors in C, C++ and Fortran programs that use the POSIX pthreads threading primitives.
>
> The main abstractions in POSIX pthreads are: a set of threads sharing a common address space, thread creation, thread joining, thread exit, mutexes (locks), condition variables (inter-thread event notifications), reader-writer locks, spinlocks, semaphores and barriers.
>
> Helgrind can detect three classes of errors, which are discussed in detail in the next three sections:
>
> 1. [Misuses of the POSIX pthreads API](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.api-checks).
> 2. [Potential deadlocks arising from lock ordering problems](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.lock-orders).
> 3. [Data races -- accessing memory without adequate locking or synchronisation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.data-races).

Problems like these often result in unreproducible, timing-dependent crashes, deadlocks and other misbehaviour, and can be difficult to find by other means.

Helgrind is aware of all the pthread abstractions and tracks their effects as accurately as it can. On x86 and amd64 platforms, it understands and partially handles implicit locking arising from the use of the LOCK instruction prefix.

Helgrind works best when your application uses only the POSIX pthreads API. However, if you want to use custom threading primitives, you can describe their behaviour to Helgrind using the ANNOTATE_* macros defined in helgrind.h. This functionality was added in release 3.5.0 of Valgrind, and is considered experimental.